# Can the Mac Music App sync with, update, or be converted to Itunes itl/xml files?

Tags: itunes, mojave, music, library, ratings

I mistakenly updated a MBP to Catalina in 2021 and suffered with the few "silent but annoying" things Apple did to push iTunes/local library users to streaming (ie, you cannot drag songs around in the up next queue with local music, but magically can with streamed content)

I recently acquired a different MBP with Mojave, and have copied my entire itunes folder to this new machine. However, my iTunes Library.iti and ITunes Music Library.xml files are back dated to 2021 and therefore none of the play counts and ratings I have made since then (on the Music app) have saved to the iti/xml files - but to "Music Library" file instead.

Is there any way to use the Music Library file or Music application to refresh/update the data of those iTunes files?

Comment: Apple has never made anything that is backwards-compatible, I'm afraid. They'd already broken the beautifully compliant xml/itl structure in Sierra, which was relatively easy to port/re-write/change, making the xml all but redundant. I wish you luck, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: Your additional issue, I'd forgotten about initially, is that all your paths will be different. Rather than being at `Macintosh HD/Users/[you]/Music/iTunes` it wil be `Macintosh HD Data/Users/[you]/Music/iTunes`. idk whether you can do a simple search/replace on the xml like you used to. Here's a whole slew of QAs I've been involved in over the years, from when it was easy, through the 'they've started to break this' era. I gave up after that. https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A85275+itl [I doubt most of this would work any more, but it may give you insight]